# How to type accessing deep object properties - getting object keys dynamically

Tags: typescript

I would like to get proper typing for accessing object properties based on provided key names. I want to get keys of object one level below.

I have following object from which I want to access some data:

```js
const source = {
  sth: {
    EXAMPLE: 'this is my example'
  },
  another: {
    TEST: 'this is my test value'
  }
};
```

Accessing function:

```
function getMessage(context : keyof typeof source, msgKey: string) : string {

    if(msgKey in source[context]) {
      return source[context][msgKey]
    }
}
```

By `keyof typeof source` I'm getting first-level keys - works like a charm.

How to get lower level keys? With `msgKey: string` of course I'm getting error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ EXAMPLE: string; } | { TEST: string; }'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ EXAMPLE: string; } | { TEST: string; }'

Of course, by `getMessage('sth', 'EXAMPLE')` I want to get `'this is my example'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the compiler hint

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ EXAMPLE: string; } | { TEST: string; }'

You need to specify the index signature for the properties of `source`:

```
interface Source {
  [key: string]: {  // First level
    [key: string]: string; // Second level
  }
}

const source: Source = {
  sth: {
    EXAMPLE: 'this is my example'
  },
  another: {
    TEST: 'this is my test value'
  }
};
```

Now you don't even need to write `keyof typeof source` for the first level as it's already implied from the `Source` interface:

```
function getMessage(context: string, msgKey: string): string {
  if(msgKey in source[context]) {
    return source[context][msgKey]
  }
}
```

#### More levels deeper

From my understanding, there is no way to specify index signatures for any dynamic level of nesting, so you have to specify them explicitly for each level. However, you could make things a bit easier with generics:

```
type Indexed<T> = {
  [key: string]: T;
}

const source: Indexed<Indexed<string>> = {
  sth: {
    EXAMPLE: 'this is my example'
  },
  another: {
    TEST: 'this is my test value'
  }
};
```

Not the most elegant thing to read when your object has three or more levels of nesting but it's an option:

```
const source: Indexed<Indexed<Indexed<Indexed<string>>>> = {};
```

Comment: You are absolutely right that I should also type my source. Anyway, with you solution compiler still warns and I'm loosing autocompletion for the first level (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwggPAFQHxQLxQDeAUFFANoDWEIAXFAM7ABOAlnAOYC698SqGHFAA+UTAG5iAX2LEAxgHs4TRgoCuzORF6IUadHz0YmbTtlwESZJgAt6VslACiADQCCAWQAKAGSf0AcmAbVgYoUKgAWxAoFABDSLAAGwgA0igpABp0uLgFYIhme3SyTCcAZUxA4IiI6KhgCBUANziktVT0mSlJWQAzNTg5YFYlKA4IYA8mhjiJgApFOEbkYHoTdg5MqIYOAGkadZZNgEoj0w4idNY++cjdg5j2VQ0tciWV4C4Tq8coZkmGjgL00EHeSk+XHI932NC4XVkZABwCBUACAUkUiAA)

Comment: That is true because the function does not know if the element returned is a string or yet another indexed object. I'll correct the type in the answer.

Comment: Thanks you Matei, this solves my problem in some way. Anyway I am still curious whether it is possible to get dynamically keys of deeper levels (as I did with first level by `keyof typeof source`